# Back button for webview used in Fragments not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onkeydown

When I use `Webview` in fragments I was not able to use `OnKeydown` method
but this method can be used in Activity file but not in fragments

```
@Override    
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web1.canGoBack()) {
        web1.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This method is not working in fragments where as it works perfectly in Activity

Comment: Could you give some *context* by posting some of your code please? It's hard to help without.

Comment: @Override     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {         if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web1.canGoBack())         {             web1.goBack();             return true;         }         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);     }.                          ---,> this method is not working in fragments where as it works perfectly in Activity

Answer (score 1):

for fragment,

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            WebView webView = (WebView) v;

            switch(keyCode)
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack())
                    {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I confirm it works perfectly. I just put the code inside a `private void` in one of the fragments and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeAmVF

Comment: I'm the one who thanks you for the remote support, Jignesh: it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom method in your fragment class(s). For example:

```
public void myOnKeyDown(int key_code){
   //do whatever you want here
}
```

and call this method whenever a key-down event is raised in your Activity class. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        ((PastEventListFragment)fragments.get(0)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode);
        ((EventListFragment)fragments.get(1)).myOnKeyDown(keyCode);

        //and so on...
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```